# Arrays not outputting correctly - C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ console application and I'm turning `a` into `1`, `b` into `2` and so on. Thing is, it's outputting numbers like 48 and 52 - even though the array I'm basing it off only goes up to 26.

Here's the code:

```
void calculateOutput() {

    while (input[checkedNum] != alphabet[checkedAlpha]) {
        checkedAlpha++;
        if (checkedAlpha > 27) {
            checkedAlpha = 0;
        }
    }

    if (input[checkedNum] == alphabet[checkedAlpha]) {
        cout << numbers[checkedAlpha] << "-";
        checkedAlpha = 0;
        checkedNum++;
        calculateOutput();
    }
}
```

Here is my number and alphabet arrays:

```
char alphabet [27] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' '};

int numbers [27] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','0' };
```

Comment: How are `input`, `alphabet`, and `numbers` defined?

Comment: Hint: `inputAlphabet - 'a' + 1` would give what you need

Comment: Where does the `numbers` array come from? Regardless, your output (stuff like 48 and so on) sounds like [ASCII values](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/ASCII-value-character).

Comment: @plezhelpmeh please edit the question with the added data...

Comment: Offish topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its `int` array so it means that it will save ASCII values of characters.

If you would look carefully on [ASCII table](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), you would find out that 48,49,50,... are ascii values of numbers 0,1,2,...

What you have to do is deduct value of first number in table -> '0' (48)

```
cout << numbers[checkedAlpha] - '0' << "-";
```

or better, save numbers as **numbers** not characters

```
 int numbers [27] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14​,15,16,17,18'​,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26​,0 };
```

Btw. here is hint which make it easier for you

```
tolower(inputAlphabet[index]) - 'a' + 1  // For 'a' output is 1 and so on :-)
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, remember that ascii table. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to get the number (i9ndex) of the letters of the alphabet is quite simple.  No need for tables, a simple subtraction does the trick.

```
int getLetterIndex(char c)
{
    // returns -1 if c is not a letter
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
        return 1 + c - 'a';
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
        return 1 + c - 'A';
    return -1; 
}
```